# Perl module to read cell content that is a reference to a cell in another sheet. Need formula or reference

Tags: excel, perl

I am reposting my question and my answer below for any of you who would like to know 
how to do this:

How does one extract a formula (including cell references) from an Excel (2007) .xlsx file using Perl?

The Problem:

Assume cell[0][0] on 'Sheet1' contains 123
Assume cell[2][2] on 'Sheet2' contains 'Sheet1'!A0  a reference to the cell on Sheet1.

Using Perl and ths module; Spreadsheet::XLSX you get the following:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::XLSX;

my $excelFile = Spreadsheet::XLSX -> new ("MyExcelFile.xlsx");

foreach my $sheet (@{$excelFile -> {Worksheet}}) {
    my $name   = $sheet -> {Name};
    if ( $name eq 'Sheet2' ) {
        my $cell = $sheet -> {Cells} [2] [2];       # cell (C3)
        my $curCellContent = $cell -> {Value};
        print "$curCellContent\n";       # OUTPUT:  123
    }
}
```

This is normally fine but I need the formula(reference): 'Sheet1'!A0

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Spreadsheet::XLSX does not handle forumlas.
The solution is to use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX instead.

```
# Tested with perl version 5.16 Spreadsheet::XLSX version 0.13
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;

my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX->new;
my $excelWorkbook  = $parser->parse("MyExcelFile.xlsx");

foreach my $sheet (@{$excelWorkbook -> {Worksheet}}) {
    my $name   = $sheet -> {Name};
    print "\$name = $name\n";
    if ( $name eq 'Sheet2' ) {
        my $cell = $sheet -> {Cells} [2] [2];               # cell (C3)
        my $curCellContentValue = $cell -> Value;
        print "$curCellContentValue\n";                     # OUTPUT: 123
        my $#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w = $cell -> {Formula};
        print "$curCellContentFormula\n";                   # OUTPUT: 'Sheet1'!A0
    }
}
```